# Highcharts Tooltips are slow in I.E. 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**Highcharts heatmap chart screen grab:**

[image]

I have a highcharts treemap (heatmap) chart built in Highcharts.  The tooltips are chocked full of details, while the datalabels are just colored symbols (font-awesome).  There are no issues in Chrome but I.E. is staggering on the movement from grid spot to grid spot where a datalabel exists and a tooltip needs to display. I get like five moves then a split second pause, then it moves and pauses again, it makes people miss their mouseover targets (and is a serious irritation). Unless someone can help me speed this up on I.E. this baby may never see the light of day (Highcharts dev team...help!!!!). I could be doing problematic things with the data here, but for the most part I tried to improve the code where I could and nothing works.

```
{
    x: 0,
    y: 17,

    myData: 'KRS-1   6153',

    value: '<i class="fa fa-square fa-2x"></i>',
    nextDetailss: "Kerble @ 30 mins",
    toolTipStringg: "<br>Bogart on: 2015-11-06<br>4:50:01 AM CST<br>This Choo is Love equiped!",

    myColor: "#66E861",
    dataLabels: {
        color: "#66E861"
    }
},
```

(above) This is how much stuff I am placing in a single grid position in the series where a datalabel and tooltip are needed.

[Here is the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/ptmjL6yx/)